# anonymous volume mount is failing with read-only file system error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I want to sync my code to docker container when developing the application so that I don't need to rebuild the image after code changes but If I delete node_modules from code on host machine (using volumes: - **'.:/app'**) then after running container it gives error because due to directory sync it deletes the node_modules from container as well.

Then I found the solution where I added one anonymous volume '/app/node_modules' to retain node_modules which works fine but gives below error if I add **:ro** flag to **'.:/app'** bind mount

Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/var/lib/docker/volumes/app_node_modules/_data" to rootfs at "/app/node_modules" caused: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e3b8c651e1793efa13352ffb5e90669badb00bb1b0f8f464aa8d65d8f6a1aa9a/merged/app/node_modules: read-only file system: unknown

Following is the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 4000:$PORT
    volumes:
      - '.:/app:ro'
      - /app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

Host Machine : Windows 11
Docker Desktop : 4.4.3 (WS2 Linux Containers)

Comment: I've generally found directly using Node without Docker to be a good approach for day-to-day development.  Docker is intended to prevent containers from unintentionally accessing host files; since Node runs directly on your host it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Fair enough, but I have multiple applications which runs on different node versions so docker makes dev easy by isolating the apps and node versions and another thing is we are a team who works on this application and we may have different OS and Hardware so docker helps to deal with that also.